# AWS SAM starting local api returns "Function name is required" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

We are using CDK to build our infrastructure configuration. Moreover, I create my `template.yml` for SAM with `cdk synth <stack_name> --no-staging > template.yml` if it helps. I am using AWS Toolkit to invoke/debug my lambda functions on Intellij which works fine. However, if I run `sam local start-api` on terminal and send a request to one of my functions then it returns an error with stacktrace;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/0.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2317, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/0.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1840, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/0.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1743, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/0.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/0.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1838, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/0.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1824, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/0.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/samcli/local/apigw/local_apigw_service.py", line 203, in _request_handler
    self.lambda_runner.invoke(route.function_name, event, stdout=stdout_stream_writer, stderr=self.stderr)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/0.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/samcli/commands/local/lib/local_lambda.py", line 84, in invoke
    function = self.provider.get(function_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/0.53.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/samcli/lib/providers/sam_function_provider.py", line 65, in get
    raise ValueError("Function name is required")
ValueError: Function name is required
```

This is the command I run

`sam local start-api --env-vars env.json --docker-network test`

which gives the output

```
Mounting None at http://127.0.0.1:3000/v1 [GET, OPTIONS, POST]
Mounting None at http://127.0.0.1:3000/v1/user [GET, OPTIONS, POST]
You can now browse to the above endpoints to invoke your functions. You do not need to restart/reload SAM CLI while working on your functions, changes will be reflected instantly/automatically. You only need to restart SAM CLI if you update your AWS SAM template
2020-08-22 16:32:46  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:3000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2020-08-22 16:33:03 Exception on /v1/user [OPTIONS]
```

And here is the env.json I am using as environment variables for my functions

```
{
  "tenantGetV1Function54F63CB9": {
    "db": "alpha",
    "connectionString": "mongodb://mongo"
  },
  "tenantPostV1FunctionA56822D0": {
    "db": "alpha",
    "connectionString": "mongodb://mongo"
  },
  "userGetV1Function7E6E55C2": {
    "db": "alpha",
    "connectionString": "mongodb://mongo"
  },
  "userPostV1FunctionEB035EB0": {
    "db": "alpha",
    "connectionString": "mongodb://mongo"
  }
}
```

I am also running Docker Desktop on macOS operating system.

EDIT: Here you can find the simplified template.yml with only one endpoint (one function definition) which is for `tenantGetV1Function54F63CB9` function. It will map to GET /v1 endpoint. I didnt want include the whole template for 4 functions which makes around a thousand lines of .yml code.

https://gist.github.com/flexelem/d887136484d508e313e0a745c30a2d97

Comment: Would you add to your question, a code block containing relevant parts of your template.yaml?

Comment: @petey definitely! I shared a gist including only one api with overridden environment variables.

Comment: that link, 404s

Comment: sorry I replaced it with another one by changing some values. please try again : )

Comment: also,  something seems to be going wrong with your OPTIONS request at `/v1/user`.  Are you using curl? or ?

Comment: hey @petey the updated template.yml only includes one function which is for `tenantGetV1Function54F63CB9` mapping to GET /v1 endpoint. Sorry for not mentioning it. I haven't tried an OPTIONS request. But I use POSTMAN instead of curl. Another thing is I am building this template with `cdk synth <stack_name> --no-staging > template.yml`. And I also found this githus issue but not sure if it is related https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/716

Comment: I'm not familar with cdk at all.  Its posible you are running into CORs issues with postman when that OPTIONS request fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem solved if I create `LambdaIntegration` by passing the `Function` instance instead of its `Alias` instance in CDK. So, we are creating lambdas along with an alias. Then, we pass the alias to their associated `Resource` instance from Api Gateway.

This is the way are creating;

```
Function tenantGetV1Function = Function.Builder.create(this, "tenantGetV1Function")
    .role(roleLambda)
    .runtime(Runtime.JAVA_8)
    .code(lambdaCode)
    .handler("com.yolda.tenant.lambda.GetTenantHandler::handleRequest")
    .memorySize(512)
    .timeout(Duration.minutes(1))
    .environment(environment)
    .description(Instant.now().toString())
    .build();

Alias tenantGetV1Alias = Alias.Builder.create(this, "tenantGetV1Alias")
    .aliasName("live")
    .version(tenantAdminGetV1Function.getCurrentVersion())
    .provisionedConcurrentExecutions(provisionedConcurrency)
    .build();

Resource v1Resource = v1Resource.addResource("{tenantId}");
v1Resource.addMethod("GET", LambdaIntegration.Builder.create(tenantGetV1Alias).build(), options);
```

And if I replace `tenantGetV1Alias` with `tenantGetV1Function` then `sam build` command successfully builds all the functions which will make `sam local start-api` to spin up them.

```
Resource v1Resource = v1Resource.addResource("{tenantId}");
v1Resource.addMethod("GET", LambdaIntegration.Builder.create(tenantGetV1Function).build(), options);
```

Somehow, SAM is not able to get function name property from CloudFormation templates if we assign aliases.

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/2227

Comment: @wprl Yup, that issue was created by me :D